# How do i disable events on FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, arrays, fullcalendar

i have the jquery fullcalendar with events like(Meeting, Birthday etc). How do i turn off the events on full calendar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable event links in FullCalendar when using Google Calendar feed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813271/how-to-disable-event-links-in-fullcalendar-when-using-google-calendar-feed)